# Python how to output characters as raw text

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I try to get the unicode number from a string that has "\xff" in it I get an error.

```
test = ord(str(tmp1))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 4 found
```

How can I avoid this?

Edit - The output of `print(repr(tmp1))` is `'\\xff'`

Edit - Is there anyway you can find the byte version of a character? eg 255 -> \xff instead of getting ÿ

Comment: it is a string that has 4 characters `\xff`, not one character 0xFF.

Comment: Please add a repeatable example to your question or at least the output of `print(repr(tmp1))`

Comment: So when my variable test has "\xff" in it and i use `ord(test)` it displays an error but if i manually type `ord("\xff")` then it works, i think this might be because the raw text is `\\xff` so it is not seen to be a byte

Answer (score 0):

you have to encode your text

```
test = ord(tmp1.encode('utf-16'))
```

this way you can avoid this error.

Comment: But then i get     `test = ord(test.encode('utf-16'))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 10 found` after using it on `'\\xff'`

Comment: make sure that you pass only one character
try to pass `tmp1[0]` instead of `tmp1`